# Validar un campo input, no nulo en HTML

Tags: html5, angular, angular5

Estoy trabajando con el framework angular y  en uno de los componentes tengo un html para hacer un login el cual quiero validar. He intentado podener el especificador 'required' y no le afecta en nada. 
Podriais ayudarme?

```
<input  type="text"
[(ngModel)]="usuario" 
placeholder="Usuario" 
name="usuario"
required />
```

Comment: Bienevido para entender mejor el funcionamiento de la pagina te invito a dar [tour]

Comment: Deberías añadir el código completo de la plantilla y del componente para poder ver qué falla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma para agregar una validación al formulario con Angular es de la siguiente manera:

```
<input  type="text" name="usuario" [(ngModel)]="usuario" #usuario="ngModel" 
placeholder="Usuario"  required />

<div *ngIf="usuario.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
     <div *ngIf="usuario.errors.required">
        Ingrese su usuario
    </div>
</div>
```

`#name="ngModel"` Instanciar el input text, para poder usar los estados de validaciones como required.

PDTA: Otra forma de validar es usando formularios reactivos, te paso la documentacion oficial de angular donde lo explica: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario"
required = true />
```